# Unable to add value to the google pie chart

Tags: javascript, php

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 name1= $("#party1_name").val();
 count1=$("#party1_count").val();
 name2= $("#party2_name").val();
var  count2=$("#party2_count").val();
 name3= $("#party3_name").val();
 count3=$("#party3_count").val();




// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  alert("Value: " + count2);
 var value1=count1;
 var value2=2;
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  [name1, value1],
  [name2, value2],
  [name3, 4],
  ['Gym', 2],
  ['Sleep', 8]
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Result Analysis', 'width':550, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
 });
```

When m taking data from the input field and adding data to dataarray like value1 variable. Nothing is displayed in the chart. but when adding value2 variable its working. i have tested using alert.. and m getting the right value but no data is displayed.

this how m adding data to the input field.

```
 <input type="text" id="party1_name" value="<?=$party_name1?>">
 <input type="number" id="party1_count" value="<?=$count_part1?>">
 <input type="text" id="party2_name" value="<?=$party_name2?>">
 <input type="text" id="party2_count" value="<?=$count_part2?>">
 <input type="text" id="party3_name" value="<?=$party_name3?>">
 <input type="text" id="party3_count" value="<?=$count_part3?>">
```

[image: this is chart output]